# OpenCV with CUDA

Tags: opencv, cmake

I'm trying to run CUDA libraries with my OpenCV project (needed for GpuMat). I've generated a solution with CMake (WITH_CUDA ON) and builded it (although it lasted 2.5h...), then created a new CUDA project and linked all the libraries. Unfortunately, while compiling the code, I get an error:

```
Error: No CUDA support (The library is compiled without CUDA support) in throw_no_cuda, file E:\OPEN_CV\opencv-master\modules\core\include\opencv2/core/private.cuda.hpp, line 107
```

[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4zQM.jpg)

I've tried copying .dll and .lib files into my project directory and updating GF960m drivers but none of them worked out. Have you got any idea?

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO! Try to compile once again, but remember to enable testings. Then make tests to see if the library was built properly.

Comment: Thank you. The problem is that building a CMake solution takes really a lot of time, lately it was about 2.5h. What's more, I get a lot od warnings like "field of class type without a DDL interface used in a class with a DLL interface". Shall I care about it?

Comment: To decrease build time you can disable unnecessary modules, as well as turn off examples and documentation. According to [this question](http://answers.opencv.org/question/60489/opencv-build-process-warning-field-of-class-type-without-a-dll-interface-used-in-a-class-with-a-dll-interface/), DDL warnings are not relevant

Comment: It is good if you can share your cmake output, to see if something is wrong there. Sometimes you have to set some other variables manually, which can be done with ccmake (linux) or cmake gui (windows). Also, it is good to say what is your OS. If you are in linux, you can do `make -j 4` for cmake to do 4 jobs in parallel to speed things up.

Comment: Thanks again. Built time dramatically increases within adding WITH_CUDA. Normally it is about 10 minutes.

Comment: Well, you are not the only one [with this observation](http://answers.opencv.org/question/73218/how-long-does-it-take-to-build-opencv-with-cuda/).

Comment: Which file should I show you? My OS is Windows 10 64.

Comment: I've totally run out of ideas

Comment: My guess is, that OpenCV was build properly, but your another project has invalid `CMakeLists.txt` and the problem is there. But until you don't show us full output of CMake process and the content of CMakeLists, it is just guessing. Building and running tests will answer, if the problem is inside main OpenCV, or within your app.

Comment: When you run the CMake GUI app, and click Configure, it shows in the bottom window, an output log. You should show it, to know if something is missing. For the slow down with cuda is that the nvidia compiler is probably compiling it for several architechtures. You can try to reduce it to only the one of your card, This is the CUDA_ARCH_BIN variable. For GF960m it is `5.0`

Comment: this is my CMake output log. https://pastebin.com/QGEpGa9f

Comment: OK, this output looks fine, what about the output of your dependent project?

Comment: looks good actually... make sure you build ALL and INSTALL... and that you link the correct libraries... other than that, I am out of ideas, maybe cleaning all build folders could help

Comment: I've rebuilded everything again. In fact, choosing only 5.0 in the CUDA_ARCH_BIN resulted in obtaining a much shorter build time. Unfortunately, I get an error: 
`Error LNK1104 cannot open file 'Files\NVIDIA.obj'`

Comment: We cannot read in your mind, if you want our help, then provide full cmake and compiler's output.

Comment: That's right. What are the exact files that you need?

Comment: Guys, maybe I am doing something wrong after generating a project via CMake? 
1) I do open OpenCV.sln, then build ALL_BUILD and INSTALL (only Debug mode).
2) Create a new project (Not a CUDA one, a normal Win32 Console Application)
3) Link (...)\OpenCV\install\include and (...)\OpenCV\install\x64\vc15\lib and all the .lib files in Input
4) Build customization -> CUDA 10.0

Comment: Indeed, you do it wrong. Your app has to be generated by Cmake, too. Look at examples, choose one and try to build it (opencv needs to be found by cmake to generate the project). If you can build an example, than modify `cmakelists.txt` to fit it to your project.